# Uploading a HyperApp web application to github, which files do I upload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperapp

Hey all I have a restaurant web app I did and would like to upload it to github when I do so which files do I need to upload ? all?  Do I need to do anything else such as compiling of any sort? Would this work the same with reAct projects ?

Answer (score 1):

u need to upload all the files. It will be good to have a description in the read.me file which shows how to install and run the app.

Comment: How do you run it once loaded on github , would you run the index.hrml to see the app on the browser ? I’m not clear on projects like this on how to actually run the project on get hub.

Comment: @joseperez u can't run it on GitHub. The instructions are for other developers who would like to download the app. So now anyone can download the app and run it depending on how u have configured it. E.g. If you are using superstatic then u will have an instruction to run the following command `superstatic --config superstatic.json`. In the JSON file u need to have something like this `{ "rewrites": [ {"source":"/**","destination":"/index.html"} ] }`. I don't have much of experience with React but I remember u need to configure it as well.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your time I’ll research your answer a bit more hopefully I can figure out an alternative